# How to extract dict columns with similar names from json array in pandas dataframe

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, json-normalize

I have a dataframe of 20k rows x 45 columns that has been normalized nearly fully, but I have one pesky column in particular.

I have copied just the index and the problem column, omitting the other 44 columns for simplicity in data display.

```
    agencies
0   [{'id': 29, 'name': 'Air Force, Dept of'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'HOUSE OF REPRESENTATIVES'}, {'id': 1, 'name': 'SENATE'}]
1   [{'id': 29, 'name': 'Air Force, Dept of'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'HOUSE OF REPRESENTATIVES'}, {'id': 1, 'name': 'SENATE'}]
2   [{'id': 2, 'name': 'HOUSE OF REPRESENTATIVES'}, {'id': 1, 'name': 'SENATE'}]
3   [{'id': 2, 'name': 'HOUSE OF REPRESENTATIVES'}, {'id': 1, 'name': 'SENATE'}]
4   [{'id': 2, 'name': 'HOUSE OF REPRESENTATIVES'}, {'id': 1, 'name': 'SENATE'}]
```

Here, I would like to extract each of the values within the `name` label, however, they all have the same name so `json_normalize()` puts them all in the same column, and lengthens the dataset by however many entries are in each array.

I would like to extract them into `name_1`, `name_2`, `name_3`, ... , `name_max_amount_of_names`. So let's suppose the max amount of `name` entries in the column is 5, I would like to have:

`name_1`, `name_2`, `name_3`, `name_4`, `name_5`.

I have tried normalization and cannot figure this out further.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT:

Thanks to the kind commenter below, I'm close, however, it seems to be creating a new column for each unique 'name', and that's not what I was trying to accomplish as it clutters the data with many NaN's.

I have included a screenshot of the results.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try as follows.

1. We apply [`Series.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) to get each item from each list on a separate row (but still with the appropriate index number).
2. We wrap this result inside [`pd.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) to get a flat table.
3. We now need to set a new index (with `apply(pd.Series)` we wouldn't have this problem) with the exploded index values (so: `.set_index(df.agencies.explode().index)`).
4. Finally, we use [`df.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) to get the data in the correct shape.
5. Now, we are basically done, except for renaming the `df.columns`.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'agencies': 
        {0: [{'id': 29, 'name': 'Air Force, Dept of'}, 
             {'id': 2, 'name': 'HOUSE OF REPRESENTATIVES'}, 
             {'id': 1, 'name': 'SENATE'}],
         1: [{'id': 29, 'name': 'Air Force, Dept of'}, 
             {'id': 2, 'name': 'HOUSE OF REPRESENTATIVES'}, 
             {'id': 1, 'name': 'SENATE'}],
         2: [{'id': 2, 'name': 'HOUSE OF REPRESENTATIVES'}, 
             {'id': 1, 'name': 'SENATE'}],
         3: [{'id': 2, 'name': 'HOUSE OF REPRESENTATIVES'}, 
             {'id': 1, 'name': 'SENATE'}],
         4: [{'id': 2, 'name': 'HOUSE OF REPRESENTATIVES'}, 
             {'id': 1, 'name': 'SENATE'}]}}
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df_names = pd.json_normalize(df.agencies.explode())\
    .set_index(df.agencies.explode().index).pivot(
        index=None,columns='id', values='name')

# order of column names will be:
# sorted(pd.json_normalize(df.agencies.explode())\
#     .set_index(df.agencies.explode().index)['id'].unique())
# i.e.: [1, 2, 29]

# (reorder them as appropriate, and then) overwrite as name_1, name_2, name_3
df_names.columns = [f'name_{idx}' for idx in range(1, len(df_names.columns)+1)]

print(df_names)

   name_1                    name_2              name_3
0  SENATE  HOUSE OF REPRESENTATIVES  Air Force, Dept of
1  SENATE  HOUSE OF REPRESENTATIVES  Air Force, Dept of
2  SENATE  HOUSE OF REPRESENTATIVES                 NaN
3  SENATE  HOUSE OF REPRESENTATIVES                 NaN
4  SENATE  HOUSE OF REPRESENTATIVES                 NaN

# assignment to orig df would be:
# df = pd.concat([df,df_names],axis=1)
```

---

**Update**
The OP has updated the question. Let's produce a small example to clarify the apparent problem. The adjusted data is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'agencies': 
        {0: [{'id': 29, 'name': 'Air Force, Dept of 29'}, 
             {'id': 1, 'name': 'SENATE'},
             {'id': 4, 'name': 'Air Force, Dept of 4'},],
         1: [{'id': 2, 'name': 'Air Force, Dept of 2'}, 
             {'id': 1, 'name': 'SENATE'}]
         }}
```

So, here we have 3 unmatched `key-value` pairs: `'id': 2`, `4`, and `29`. Applying the method described above, we will end up with this:

```
   name_1                name_2                name_3                 name_4
0  SENATE                   NaN  Air Force, Dept of 4  Air Force, Dept of 29
1  SENATE  Air Force, Dept of 2                   NaN                    NaN
```

Here, the names associated with `id: 1` work fine (`name_1`), because this key is found in *both* lists of dicts. However, the other `name` keys all lack a "match" in the other list, so that they end up with their own column in consecutively order (based on the `ids`). I.e. `name_2` fills names associated with `'id': 2`, then `name_3` for `4`, and `name_4` for `29`.

If I understand the update correctly, the OP rather wishes to "use up" each new consecutive `name` column with `name`-keys as much as possible, before creating a new column. I.e., in the current example, this would mean that `name_2` is to be filled with the name for `'id': 4` in row `0`, and `'id': 2` in row `1`. And then only the name for `'id': 29` will get its own column (`name_3`), since `name_2` is already "full". We can achieve this quite easily by adding an intermediate step:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

first = pd.json_normalize(df.agencies.explode())

second = first.set_index(df.agencies.explode().index)

# rank all `ids` per group, and overwrite the original `ids`
# i.e. [1, 4, 29] -> [1, 2, 3]
second['id'] = second.groupby(level=0)['id'].rank()

final = second.pivot(index=None,columns='id', values='name')

final.columns = [f'name_{idx}' for idx in range(1, len(final.columns)+1)]

print(final)

   name_1                name_2                 name_3
0  SENATE  Air Force, Dept of 4  Air Force, Dept of 29
1  SENATE  Air Force, Dept of 2                    NaN
```

Comment: This is sensational, thank you! However, it's throwing a key error with 'id'. I checked and ID is indeed in every column within the dataset, so that's rather odd.

Comment: But is it "ID" (all CAPS) or "id"? My code here expects "id". If your actual data has "ID", simply alter `columns='id'` accordingly.

Comment: It does not, it's in the same format that you posted. The dataframe stucture is exactly the same from what I can tell, just 20k rows

Comment: Could you maybe cut up the one-liner and check on what specific part it throws the error. So, instead of the one-liner, run `one = pd.json_normalize(df.agencies.explode())`, and `two = one.set_index(df.agencies.explode().index)`, and `three = two.pivot(index=None,columns='id', values='name')`. And also check what those variables look like at the various stages. E.g. `print(two.head())`. Do you see anything odd there?

Comment: Upon trying `one = pd.json_normalize(df.agencies.explode())` it's just returning the index with no values within, where yours has values and id. This is the correct approach, but unsure what's going on with my dataframe structure. I copy/pasted directly from df.head()

Comment: I've edited the OP to show the current issue. If you're unsure of a fix, this will suffice, but I'm trying to navigate around it at the moment. `name_1`, `name_2`, `name_3` might all have different row entries but will all be under `name_1`, `name_2`, and `name_3` rather than be a new column for each unique value.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the answer. Hopefully, this solves your problem. Let me know if you experience any difficulties in applying the suggested method or if your problem is still not solved by the updated suggestion.

Comment: This is a perfect fix; thank you sincerely. I have been stuck on this for days.